# Formatting Numbers to Army Time (Big Java Ex. 4.15)

Tags: java

I just started learning Java last week and am currently stuck on my exercise. Basically the problem is you take two numbers in army time, and then output what the difference is For example

```
Please Enter First time : 0900
Please Enter second time: 1730
Result - > 8 hours and 30 minutes
```

The bonus of the problem is to make sure the program works if the first time is bigger than the second. First I'm trying to solve the first part and heres what I have so far

```
    class TimeInterval{
        private double timeOne;
        private double timeTwo;
        public TimeInterval(double timeOne, double timeTwo){
            timeOne = this.timeOne;
            timeTwo = this.timeTwo;
        }

        public double getMinutes(){
            double minuteDiff = timeTwo - timeOne;
            minuteDiff = minuteDiff%60.0;
            return minuteDiff;
        }
        public double getHours(){
            double hours = timeTwo - timeOne;
            hours = hours - getMinutes();
            hours = hours/60.0;
            return hours;   
    }
}

public class DataSet{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        TimeInterval time = new TimeInterval(0900,1730);

    }
}
```

Now heres whats trippy. I'd like to make my new object with `timeOne` as `0900`, but I'm getting an error. It says "Integer too long", that seems pretty funny to me so I did some research. In the last section of my book in chapter 4 we talking about formatting stuff, like with `System.out.printf`, and like `%d, %f`

I looked on SO and I found a way where I can do something like

```
String.format("%05d", yournumber);
```

Here you can put 5 0's before your number. The thing is, I'm not really sure how to implement this into my code. I tried setting timeTwo = String.format... etc, but then since its a string I can't really do math on it. Also it won't let me convert it to a double after `String.format.` How should I do approach my issue?

Comment: You must be from the United States where 24-hour time is referred to as [military time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_time). Most of the  rest of the world is “bi-lingual” using both 12-hour clock and 24-hour clock, the former for casual matters and the latter for important matters semiconductor as train schedules. So better to use the terminology "24-hour clock".

Comment: Ah perhaps formally. I call it like that in canada and no ones had problems understanding me.

Comment: To quote the Wikipedia article I linked: “It is popularly referred to as military time in the United States,[4] anglophone Canada, and a handful of other countries[1] where the 12-hour clock is still dominant." That covers about 0.4 of the 7.4 billion people on earth.

Comment: I see. We'll I didn't know that. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeric literals that start with a zero are interpreted as [*octal*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers, base 8, which can only use digits 0-7.

Thus the numeric literal `0900` is an invalid *octal* number. Try:

```
TimeInterval time = new TimeInterval(900, 1730);
```

---

Tip: Avoid using `double` for you fields and parameters. Use `int` instead, which will not suffer the imprecision of `double`. `int` can handle any number/time you need.

Comment: Yeah your right, I thought I would have to do math with the numbers at first so I made them doubles. All right, I get that I can't do 0900, but is there a way to transform my variable so I can input 0900? In a different numeric system perhaps, I'm not too knowledgable about octal numbers or anything, but there has to be a way right?

Comment: @cres if you want to "enter data", I assume you mean a String? If so, you can parse a String to an int like this `int num = Integer.parseInt("1234");`

Comment: I just meant, for learning purposes is there a way I can reconfigure my double so that It will accept x amount of 0's before 900 or something of that sort? So that this will indeed work once I put (0900,1730)?

Comment: @cre sounds like you need to input/define your data as Strings. `Integer` will parse leading zeroes OK. eg `String timeStr = "0900"; int time = Integer.parseInt(timeStr);` will function correctly.